# System.Net.WebException when access api

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I got a weird problem today. I want to test my phone on wifi out of my company network. Since I need to access my company's API, I append a token to the url request. It works fine if my computer is in guest network and I test on emulator. However, if I test it on the phone and my phone is in guest network, I get this "System.Net.Webexception". It says "The remote server returned an error: NotFound.". Any idea why? Thanks!

Fei

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NotFound` is a generic error that can be displayed in a wide variety of cases. Probably causes (without seeing your code):

- Problem with the API you are using
- The proxy settings are configured to block specific domains, that might impact web resource accessibility
- The connection quality - might cause timeouts
- Invalid data returned from the server

Comment: Hi Dennis, thanks for your answer. I found the reason of this problem. It's because I didn't set the date on the phone correctly so it impacted my token generation.